# Difference if the code is in a function

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$img=imagecreatefrompng('http://partner-ad.photobucket.com/albums/g46/xanatha/WidgieWorld/Small-Yellow-Ball.png');

function foo($x,$y)
{
    $col=imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);
    $col=imagecolorsforindex($img,$col);
    var_dump($col);
}
foo(0,0);

echo '<br />';

$col=imagecolorat($img,0,0);
$col=imagecolorsforindex($img,$col);
var_dump($col);
```

At first glance, we would think that it will output the same result twice.

But the output is:

```
NULL
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(255) ["blue"]=> int(255) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
```

How could it be?
What must I do to put the code in a function and to make it work?

Comment: Dup of [Why am I getting an "Undefined variable" notice in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1050359/), [PHP: Variable Scope Question/Referencing Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1276448/), ["Undefined Variable" notice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2146046/). This shows one good reason to have [error reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) set as high as possible (`E_ALL | E_STRICT` in <= 5.3, `E_ALL` in >= 5.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try passing the `$img` as argument?

Or if you really insist not passing `$img` as argument. You could also put that at the top of your function.

```
global $img;
```

As someone said it this question. `$img` wasn't defined in the function scope. To access it, you either have to use `global` if its a global variable. Or you have to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: but really, don't use global!

Comment: In php, if we put `$img;` at the top it's not global !?!?!?!?

Comment: If it's not in a class or in a function, i'm pretty sure it's global since php is just mashing up all php files in one big file. It should be usable by any file included after that declaration if my memory isn't playing some game with me

Comment: @LoïcFaureLacroix I was used to javascript.

Comment: One last thing, check your php.ini etc. You should configure php to throw you in the face every warnings and errors. It will save you one day. Btw don't worry, i'm not a PHP programmer.

Answer (score 1):

`$img` is not visible inside the function. You must use the keyword global inside the function to make it visible.

```
$img=imagecreatefrompng('http://partner-ad.photobucket.com/albums/g46/xanatha/WidgieWorld/Small-Yellow-Ball.png');

function foo($x,$y)
{
    global $img; //<--------------Makes $img visible inside the function
    $col=imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);
    $col=imagecolorsforindex($img,$col);
    var_dump($col);
}
foo(0,0);

echo '<br />';

$col=imagecolorat($img,0,0);
$col=imagecolorsforindex($img,$col);
var_dump($col);
```

See [php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo($x,$y,$img)
{
    $img_png = imagecreatefrompng($img);
    $col=imagecolorat($img_png,$x,$y);
    $col=imagecolorsforindex($img_png,$col);
    var_dump($col);
}
foo(0,0,'http://partner-ad.photobucket.com/albums/g46/xanatha/WidgieWorld/Small-Yellow-Ball.png');
```

It's Unable to access that variable defined outside the function.

Comment: `NULL` (because you must pass `imagecreatefrompng('http://partner-ad.photobucket.com/albums/g46/xanatha/WidgieWorld/Small-Yellow-Ball.png')` as argument)

Answer (score 0):

Variables have *function scope*. `$img` is not defined and not available inside your `foo` function. You need to pass it into the function as well.

Comment: It exists in the *global scope*, yes, but that's also the reason why it does not exist inside your *function's scope*. It's not a *superglobal* that exists everywhere.

Comment: Thanks (I was used to the javascript way)